# BlobStorage connection string configuration within .net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am having issues when it comes to deploying to azure, It is unable to configure for the storage account as I used an environment variable to store it which works perfectly for local use.

Where is the best place to configure a blob storage connection string - I have already got a connection string for an sql database stored in appsettings.json can I store the connection string for the blob storage there as well ?

I tried to use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string) to get an understanding but couldn't quite grasp it

Comment: is it a .net core web project?

Comment: @IvanYang Yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a .net core azure web app, you can still save the storage account connection string as environment variable.

For example, after deploying it to azure, then in azure portal -> your azure web app -> in the left pane, click `Configuration` -> Then in the `Application settings`, click `New application setting` -> then put your `storage account connection string` there -> click `OK` button, at last click `Save` button. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Then in your code, you can still use the code below to read the `storage account connection string`:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myStorageAccount_connstr",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying storage account key locally is not the best idea because of security risks, better generate a SAS token:

Go to Portal -> storage account -> Shared access signature -> Generate SAS token.

[image: Generate storage account SAS]

Then use generated SAS token to connect to blob storage.
Below there is a C# program that creates a new storage blob from the local file.
To run the program first install the packages **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob** and **Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common** and replace you SAS token

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string sasToken = "?sv=2020-02-10&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2021-02-25T06:53:06Z&st=2021-02-17T22:53:06Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(sasToken);

        const string accountName = "my-storage-account";
        const string blobContainerName = "my-container";
        const string blobName = "new-new-blob";
        const string myFileLocation = @"f:\my-local-file.txt";

        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, accountName, null, true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        cloudBlob.UploadFromFile(myFileLocation);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can [Acquire a token from Azure AD for authorizing requests from a client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet). Also you can read more about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview

Comment: Thank you for the response, Is it not bad practice to use the token in the code directly ?

Comment: Okay thank you ! So a token is nothing like a connection string or a key ?